# Motor sizing for modelling

Tags: mechanical, electrical

Im working on a headrest for a car that will electrically adjust up and down and have drawn up my plans. it now comes to the important questions, such as what motor to use. Ive been looking at motor sizing online but not found anything particularly helpful as im left with gaps and questions. i want a motor with a gear to raise and lower the arm of the headrest.

lets say:
m=1kg,
r of gear=0.03m,
t to max height=5s,
max height=1m,
gravity=9.81
(not my planned figures but random as id like to run the calculations myself)

What should my motor speed, load torque, inertia, stall torque, no load speed, armature inductance ect.?

if anyone knows the correct steps to go about this and can use my example values to explain or knows of a good link i would be grateful

Comment: Is gravity random now?

Comment: Inerta you calculate by reducing your system to a simple rotation. Mass itself is not really super useful here, without knowing the inertia of the rotating components.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution is to use a *gearmotor* which contains both the motor and the reduction gear to furnish a convenient actuator speed. Since the power needed to move the headrest is quite small, a small gear motor will be adequate. In this context, "small" means about the same size as that used in motor-driven car door lock mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you, ill look into that! looks perfect for the job. Do you know of any good links to run through the calculations?

Comment: No, I would just hit up Marlon p. Jones website and buy a couple of likely candidates!

Answer (score 0):

F=Force required=9.81x1.0+friction N

P=Power required=Fx1/5  W

T=Torque required=Fx0.03 Nm

In practice you'll use a small motor and won't use just a rack and pinion, you'll have other gears or a ballscrew. Friction is likely to be at least as much as the nominal force needed.